# Angular 7 - Splice and Remove (Dropdown Values) from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have an open dropdown with multiple options. I created a simple pickList out of with two. I am using splice to remove selected values from the array after button click but when the selection is multiple, splice seems to remove all but the ones selected.

*For example*: in my list to the right - if i choose San Francisco, Miami, Boston and Las Vegas then move them over to the selected box on the right. This works perfect.

[image]

**The issue is choosing Boston & Miami then clicking the left arrow to remove, removes all but the selected ones. I have used splice before but I do not remember it ignoring the items in array.**

And my code component looks like this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="foundLocations" multiple="multiple">
    <option *ngFor="let locOption of locations" [ngValue]="locOption" >
      {{ locOption }}
    </option>
</select>
<div class="selectButtons">
  <button (click)="selectThese()">></button>
    <br/>
  <button (click)="removeThese()"><</button>
</div>
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedLocations" multiple="multiple">
    <option *ngFor="let chosen of pickedLocationItems" [ngValue]="chosen" >
      {{ chosen }}
    </option>
</select>
```

and in my component looks like:

```
  foundLocations: any;
  selectedLocations: any = [];
  pickedLocationItems: any = [];

  locations: any = ["San Francisco", "Seattle", "Las Vegas", "Toronto", "Boston", "Miami", "Altantic City"];

  selectThese() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.foundLocations.length; i++) {
      this.checkSelLocation(this.foundLocations[i]);
    }
  }

  checkSelLocation(x: any) {
    console.log("Check sel locations");
    console.log(x);
    this.pickedLocationItems.push(x);
  }

  removeThese() {
    for (var g = 0; g < this.selectedLocations.length; g++) {
      this.pickedLocationItems.splice(g, 1); 
    }
  }
```

I have a Stackblitz [example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ypkdv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, change you **removeThese** method as below

1. Index which you are choosing to splice is wrong(because index of g starts from 0 and actual selected location may not start with index -0 )
2. First find index by **indexOf**
3. Splice using that index

`removeThese() {
    for (var g = 0; g < this.selectedLocations.length; g++) {
      this.pickedLocationItems.splice(this.pickedLocationItems.indexOf(this.selectedLocations[g]), 1); 
    }
  }`

working code sample for reference- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwwevl?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Took a bit of time for me to realize it was an issue with the index. Thanks, i used your example after almost giving up and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Splice is the wrong tool here. What you want to do is `filter` out any elements that are selected like so:

```
removeThese() {
    this.pickedLocationItems = this.pickedLocationItems.filter(item => !this.selectedLocations.includes(item));
  }
```

`Array.splice` removes a range of elements starting at an index, so in order to use that, you would need to find the index of each selected item and splice that index, because the selection may not be contiguous. The way you were using it, you were looping from 0 to the length of the selection array, which does not correspond to the index of the selected elements. Using `Array.filter` gets the job done in one go by removing all values that exist in the selection array.